# Display system+client in Eclipse ADT tab description?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, abap, abap-adt

We have just switched to Eclipse ADT in our SAP ABAP development environment, and now we are developing in client 100 and test in client 200, so we have opened two tabs with the same source in different SAP clients.

In the project pane we see

[image: Project Explorer]

The problem is that you cannot see the client in the tab description, currently I only see

> [D10] Z_WEB_COMPONENT | COMPONENTCONTROLLER

or something like this

[image: Editor Pane]

but I would like to see something like

> [D10 **- 100**] Z_WEB_COMPONENT | COMPONENTCONTROLLER

or

> [D10 **- 200**] Z_WEB_COMPONENT | COMPONENTCONTROLLER

This is quite confusing if to work with a several tabs of the same systems without knowing client.

Is this possible? If yes, where is this setting?

Comment: that is because you named projects similarly starting from D10_XXXX. Show the screen of your Eclipse left pane with ABAP projects

Comment: Nope. As you see in my posting - I added screenshots of the project explorer and the editor pane - the name of the Project is irrelevant. It only takes the name of the system but not the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be impossible now by standard ADT tools.

Try [this plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/abap-continuous-integration) that allows changing coloring in editor.

[image]

If to set up different colors for different projects, it should fulfill exactly what you need: one project is **E50_100**, another is **E50_200** and you can differentiate them by color

[image]

Comment: Okay I think this must be enough. Thanks.